# Handle Keycloak realms with special characters in realm name

Tags: keycloak, idp

Unfortunately I had quick fingers and created a realm via the Keycloak Management UI with the name:

%4432223232"4898483434_

looks like this:

> {
> "id" : "%4432223232\"4898483434_",
> "realm" : "%4432223232\"4898483434_",
> "notBefore" : 0,
> "revokeRefreshToken" : false,

You cannot access the settings of such a realm via the UI... so you are really stuck. KEycloak version is latest 12.x image.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this realm I used the kcadm.sh:

delete the realm:

> ./kcadm.sh delete realms/%254432223232%224898483434_ --no-config --server http://localhost:8080/mypath-01/auth --realm master --user <user> --password <password>

check if it was deleted:

> ./kcadm.sh get realms --no-config --server http://localhost:8080/mypath-01/auth --realm master --user <user> --password <password>

Comment: Another approach is to use the Admin Rest API